# Compile failure when including files with GCC

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, include

I'm trying to compile a program with gcc, but I keep getting an error that it can't find the files I've specified to include.
My code (a simplified version of what I'm trying to do which highlights the issue):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

}
```

I'm compiling with gcc, using:

```
gcc test.c -I~/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0
```

which gives me

```
test.c:1:21: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

However,

```
ls ~/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0/gtk | grep gtk.h
```

returns

```
gtk.h
gtkcheckbutton.h
gtkcheckmenuitem.h
gtkshow.h
```

so I'm not sure where I'm messing up.
My OS is Mac OSX 10.8.5, and GCC is version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either:

1. Put a space in front of the tilde:

> -I ~/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0

2. Use the absolute path:

> -I /users/username/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0

3. or use `$HOME`:

> -I $HOME/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0

Shell only does tilde expansion if the `~` is the first nonquoted character in a word. The way you've got it now, shell has no clue that this is trying to point to the users home directory.